# Magento 1.9.3 Command Line Not Available

Tags: magento-1.9, command-line

I have a quick question regarding the command line tool seen in Magento 2. I've been using it and it's amazing cool.

However now I'm working on an older version of Magento 1.9.3 and I see there isn't a command line tool. Am I wrong, or is there one? I can't seem to figure it out. I do see however a folder called /shell in my default directory that allows some basic reindexing commands. Is the command line tool a new feature for Magento 2 only?

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be talking about the php bin/magento CLI tool.

This is something that is wonderful and indeed there is one for M1 - however its not built in and you need to add it to your server. Its called Mage Tools (what we call it around the office)

install link:: 
https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

Is that the answer you were looking for?